# phantomjs japanese/chinese websites

Tags: phantomjs, baidu

I am having some issues with phantomjs when it comes to chinese/japanese websites. At first it thought the problem was with the screen capture. But it turns out, it's also a problem with a simple page.open. (see below)

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.qq.com', function(status) {

  console.log(status);
});
```

The execution goes on indefinitely, whereas for other websites such as facebook.com it returns success without issues.

Could any one indicate why this could be happening?
When i would try and use the capture feature using render, I would get messages similar to the below:

```
baidu.com
TypeError: null is not a constructor (evaluating 'g.m("ytbin.www.pageframe.setup")()')

  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vflpLdWUR/base.js:144 in c
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflTmp1fT/spf.js:14
  :0 in forEach
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflTmp1fT/spf.js:7 in u
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflTmp1fT/spf.js:14 in Ha
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflTmp1fT/spf.js:17 in Ua
  https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/spf-vflTmp1fT/spf.js:7
```

and

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'toConfig.oid')

  http://ra.gtimg.com/web/crystal/v2.6Beta05Build050/crystal-min.js:178 in callback
  http://ra.gtimg.com/web/crystal/v2.6Beta05Build050/crystal-min.js:182
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could assist.

(further info:
Tried both on Windows 10 and Mac OSX El Capitan

Also tried compiling phantomjs from source, but encountered issues on Mac OSX El Captian, for which there are no fixes as yet)

Thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by "goes on indefinitely"

When I run www.qq.com through PhantomJsCloud it renders fine:
http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22http://www.qq.com%22,renderType:%22png%22}